# Cant use mongodb after migrating parse database (using digital ocean migration tutorials)

Tags: mongodb, digital-ocean, parse-server

I have never set up a server myself and I thought that seeing as I have to migrate my parse app I may as well have a go at it.

I have a database that I am moving from Parse to digital ocean. I have a droplet (ubuntu 14.0.4.4 x64) where I log in as a non root user with sudo privileges. I have followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-14-04) tutorial to get mongo set up on the droplet.

Then I have followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-run-parse-server-on-ubuntu-14-04) tutorial step by step to get the example running on the droplet, which seems to work fine.

Now I am following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-migrate-a-parse-app-to-parse-server-on-ubuntu-14-04) tutorial to migrate my existing data over. I have followed the tutorial step by step up to the part where I migrate the data from the parse.com browser. This seems to work fine as I receive the email from Parse saying that "Your Parse Data Migration for  Is Ready To Be Finalised!".

The strange thing is, is that when I try to start mongo through terminal I get the error:

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.12
connecting to: test
2016-08-01T19:45:22.383-0400 I NETWORK  DBClientCursor::init call() failed
2016-08-01T19:45:22.388-0400 E QUERY    Error: DBClientBase::findN: transport error: 127.0.0.1:27017 ns: admin.$cmd query: { whatsmyuri: 1 }
at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179:14)
at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179
exception: connect failed
```

As I said I am new to using servers and am relying on these tutorials and hopefully help from the community here.

Thanks for your time

Comment: before migrating the data it worked ?

Comment: Ye the Parse example app worked

Comment: not the parse app but did you try to connect to your mongoDB before you migrate the data?